# Outlook: Make search case sensitive?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have a project called "DR", so I need to search for "DR" in Outlook 2007. Either I'd like to search for the sole word "DR" (not contained within words) or "DR" case sensitive.

How can this be accomplished?

I tried `" DR "` but that did not return results with the sole word "DR".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that the built-in search in Outlook can perform case sensitive searches, but there are third party alternatives, two of which (Lookeen and Xobni) are covered here: [External tools to search Microsoft Outlook 2007](http://blog.gnu-designs.com/external-tools-to-search-microsoft-outlook-2007)